# Are running JVMs affected by JRE upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, java, upgrade

The title pretty much says it all:

I would like to perform an `apt-get upgrade` on my server to get the latest JRE (among other packages), but there are a couple of JVMs running which should not be stopped. Is it safe to do the upgrade?

Ubuntu 12.04
OpenJDK 7 JRE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The currently running JVM are not affected by the upgrade process.

For example: Tomcat daemon didn't get restarted, neither did manually executed programs (`java -jar myproject.jar`).

Consequently, I guess those processes are still using the old verions; but they will use them the next time they get restarted.